# Only get scripts out of HTML file

Tags: python, html, split

I have a large html file that contains the full code from a website. I only care about the code inside `<script>...<script/>`. Is there a way to easily just take those lines out of the html file? Or will I have to split the file by each `<script>`? I'll want to ignore the parts that come before the first `<script>` (like the head) and I need to ignore the tags at the end of the file as well in the middle like where it switches from `<head>` to `<body>`.

Comment: Use a specific html parser, like BeautifulSoup for that job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want remove All script tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pagehtml = '''
<li> Text 1 </li>
<script>
<li> Text 2 </li>
<li> Text 3 </li>
</script>
<li> Text 4 </li>
<script>
<li> Text 5 </li>
</script>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, 'html.parser')
[s.extract() for s in soup.findAll('script')]
```

---

```
>>> soup

<li> Text 1 </li>

<li> Text 4 </li>

>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse html it's recommended to use a html parser library, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start), this job is not hard:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pagehtml = '''
<li> Text 1 </li>
<script>
<li> Text 2 </li>
<li> Text 3 </li>
</script>
<li> Text 4 </li>
<script>
<li> Text 5 </li>
</script>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, 'html.parser')
```

Now, to return a list with all `script` tags, and it's insides, we do:

```
>>> soup.findAll("script")
[<script>
<li> Text 2 </li>
<li> Text 3 </li>
</script>, <script>
<li> Text 5 </li>
</script>]
```

So, the first is:

```
>>> soup.findAll("script")[0]
<script>
<li> Text 2 </li>
<li> Text 3 </li>
</script>
```

And the second is:

```
>>> soup.findAll("script")[1]
<script>
<li> Text 5 </li>
</script>
```