# Extracting <script> from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, conditional-comments

I'm searching through an html file with BeautifulSoup's `find_all` function. I'm having a couple problems with this. First, since I want to find only the `<script>` tags, I have to use `soup.find_all('script')` since it won't let me have the `<,>` in the `find_all()`. Is there a way to get around this? Just by searching `script` I'm getting parts of the HTML file that are not a script tag but parts that use the word script in a URL or paragraph.

Second, when I use `soup.find_all('script')`, there are certain HTML files where not all script tags are returned. In some files, these are `<script>`'s in the `<head>` of the file and other's, the page parameters are dealt with in the scripts. Is there a way to get around this and force all script tags to be returned?

For example, one of the ignored `<script>`'s look like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script src="//www.webiste.com" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<![endif]-->
```

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(open(file), 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all('script')
```

I'm trying to grab every `<script>...</script>` section out of the HTML file. This has been the easiest way I've found to do it, but if anyone knows of an easier way that will also fix my other problems I'm open to changing my code.

Comment: You posted a similar question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149279/only-get-scripts-out-of-html-file
If none of the answers helped you, you should comment on them, asking two questions regarding a similar problem and not accepting any of the answers in one of them is not a recommended behaviour in SO.

Comment: `soup.find_all('script')` is correct. What are examples of script tags that are not returned?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar This is an elaboration and a new problem I am having related to a previous question asked. I am not reasking how to find certain substrings in a HTML file, I am having problems when I am using the suggestions you and the other person replied with on my last question. In my previous question, I didn't know about `find_all` and that's a function I needed help finding. In this question, I clearly stated that I used it, but was having errors with it.

Comment: @jesssmith It's ok then!

Comment: Sorry, I meant concrete examples, as in a [mcve]. Take the source of one of the pages where it isn’t working, trim it down to a minimal test case, and edit it into your question along with your code, please.

Comment: That script is inside a comment (so is not actually a script in modern browsers) and only runs on IE <7. Are you sure you need to extract it?